# Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length"

Tags: powershell

if you can please help with the below error. I'm getting below errors on these lines. It does create the account. It does Convert the first letter of First name to Capital, and same for Surname. However after it execute it throws the following error. It goes on until I stop it.

```
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
        $FirstName = $User.FirstName.Substring(0,1).toupper() + $User.FirstName.Substring(1).tolower()
        $LastName = $User.LastName.Substring(0,1).toupper() + $User.LastName.Substring(1).tolower()
        $SAM = $user.FirstName + $user.LastName.Substring(0,1)



Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name:  length" At C:\Users\student\Automate\CreateADaccount copy.ps1:17

char:5
+ $FirstName = $User.FirstName.Substring(0,1).toupper() + $User.d ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException   Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length" At C:\Users\student\Automate\CreateADaccount copy.ps1:18 char:5
+ $LastName = $User.LastName.Substring(0,1).toupper() + $User.d ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Comment: Use `$ErrorActionPreference = *stop'`. Then check the values for offending `$user`'s First and last name.

Comment: This simply means there are users in your array where either the FirstName or LastName (or even both) are empty strings. Check your input for that. P.S. It would be much easier to pinpoint if you show us the (sanitized) input file and the command you use to read that into the `$Users` array.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `Title Case` and the same can be achieved with the below,

```
$SAM = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($User.Firstname.ToLower()) + $User.Lastname.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()
```

Or,

```
$Firstname = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($User.Firstname.ToLower())
$Lastname = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($User.Lastname.ToLower())
$Lastname_Initials = $Lastname.Substring(0,1)
$SAM = $Firstname + $Lastname_Initials
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The error is still there for $SAM  At C:\Users\student\Automate\CreateADaccount copy.ps1:24 char:4
+    $SAM = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($User.FirstName.ToLower ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Okay, then as @Theo has mentioned in comments to your question, you must check if your input file (e.g. csv) data is in proper format (i.e. without blanks). Make sure to also check if the last row of data in the csv file contains user firstname and lastname values. You can jump to the last used row in Excel by pressing the key combination `Ctrl + End`